# How to serve a production vertion of a Dotnet Core MVC app witha Gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, gatsby

Hello I am building a new website in Gatsby.JS and I have an existing Dotnetcore MVC. The Gatsby.js website is an upgrade of some pages from the dotnetcore app but I do need some pages from the old dotnet core app. For this I have manage to put the build version of the gatsby site in the wwwroot so the dotnetcore app will serve and when an I access the old routes the will be save. It works but I dont think this is the best approach. Any suggestions?